# ASP.Net Directory Security

Tags: asp.net, web-services, impersonation

I have a directory on the root of my website which contains some files(usually html). These files should be accessed only for the logged-in user. How can I achieve this? I believe this could be done using impersonation but I don't have any idea  about how exactly I can implement it. Could you please guide me on right direction?

Currently, I have added these settings to my Web.config file:

```
<location path="TestData"> <!-- 'TestData' is the directory which I want to deny access for -->
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Is there anything that I have to do in coding?

PS: This is a webservice application.

**Update:** It works partially!!! to be specific:
It denies only the `.aspx` pages and even the logged-in user too cannot access the files.

I'm using `Windows` authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to impersonate.  If you have forms or windows authentication, your `<deny users="?"/>` will deny all anonymous users.  To answer your question: no, you don't have to explicitly deny any users within your code.

[How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx)

In order to secure non-ASP.NET files, you will need to register an `HttpHandler` that will do this.  Please see [this reference on how to register the handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Knvn did you take out the `impersonate` section?  You shouldn't be getting partial access, as you have directory authorization.

Comment: Ya I tried by removing `impersonate` section but still it works only for `.aspx` and not for other types such as `.html` or `.txt`

Comment: @Knvn see my edit.  It's because these are files that ASP.NET (for performance reasons) doesn't secure.  You need to implement `IHttpHandler` to create your own handler for these file times and have them registered.  Information in my post above.

Comment: Thank you so much...now it works for all types. However, another issue is not solved! I'm unable to browse the file even though I logged-in!

Comment: @Knvn so you can access it but not browse it?

Comment: I want the files to be able to browse/access only if the user is logged in

Comment: @Knvn I think that should be another question/post here on SO.  We try not to double-up on questions.  If this post has helped you, please mark it as the answer.  Then post a new question with your other question to comply with site rules.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need impersonate. Impersonate is for making the app run as a different user from the user of the app pool in iis. [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

If you're using forms/windows authentication then

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

should be enough and will block users who are not logged in

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

in `<system.web></system.web>`

And use form authentication like

[Update] : As you use **windows** authentication see

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9.aspx)

Comment: I could use `Forms` authentication, if it is a web application...but its a webservice application and I'm authenticating by returning the appropriate values to the client application(flash).